# NiFi 1.11 opening more than 50K files

Tags: apache-nifi

We've recently upgraded our **NiFis from 1.8 to 1.11.**

The new version however is presenting a problem. It's not closing its file handles.

The application is opening about a thousand files per hour with no apparent limit.
We have modified Amazon Linux limits to 50,000 files per user but that only delays the failure point from a few hours to a few days.

Has anyone had the same issue and found a solution?

Comment: Can you share some more info on this? The 1.11.1 release vote is underway at the moment, and if you have a strategy to reproduce this we need to chase it down.

Comment: What does it say when you run `lsof -p pid`? How many files are open with active file handles?

Comment: we need to see the lsof output.  ideally two sets of lsof output an hour apart.  this will make whatever it is easy to find.

Comment: @MikeThomsen  I'm actually using lsof to count the open files. It shows a increasing quantity of files. What I've noticed is that half of the increase can be attributed to unix pipes.

Comment: Another thing I noticed. The problem only happens if NiFi receives a HTTP connection (i.e.: via a remote incoming port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is supposed to have been fixed in 1.11.3 as stated in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7114

Comment: Can confirm that it has been fixed.